# CSS Advanced OTF features don't work

Tags: html, css

I have the following HTML + CSS source code. I want it to use advanced otf features, but the style set feature doesn't work.

```
<style>
body { font-family: source sans pro; font-size:12px }
.advotf { -moz-font-feature-settings: "ss01" 1; -moz-font-feature-settings: "onum" 1; }
</style>
<body>
<p>Regular 1234567890</p>
<p class="advotf">advanced 1234567890</p>
</body>
```

Also, free fonts on my computer containing those features don't work in any way.

Comment: your html is not currently well formed.  wrap the entire document in `html` tags and wrap the `style` tags in `head` tags - not sure if this is causing your problem, but it's not helping...

Comment: @dav1dsm1th: Based on the term "well formed" I think you're thinking of XHTML. While these rules apply to XHTML they don't apply to HTML (HTML doesn't have a concept of well formedness). If anything, the only things missing are a doctype header and a title element, otherwise the rest of the markup is valid and shouldn't cause problems.

Comment: @BoltClock I'm sure you are correct - I've just seen problems and inconsistencies with the way documents are interpreted if the `html` and `head` tags are omitted or badly formed.  Having no  `doctype` (as you point out) is not ideal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several issues involved:

1. [Support to OpenType features](http://caniuse.com/font-feature) in browsers is limited, and to get the best coverage, you should use the `-webkit-` prefixed version and (for IE) the non-prefixed version in addition to the `-moz-` prefixed version.
2. The property settings are not cumulative. When one rule contains several settings for a property, only the last one takes effect, according to general CSS principles. You need to combine the settings into one declaration.
3. Although Source Sans Pro has several OpenType features, they are not supported by the Google-hosted version. This is a general problem with Google fonts.
4. Although the [FontSquirrel @font-face generator](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator) has Expert settings for enabling OpenType features, this does not mean enabling them for use with CSS properties. Instead, they hard-wire the settings into the font files. So you can generate, for example, font files for Source Sans Pro with `onum` enabled (old-style numbers), but then these files use old-style numbers. Generating different font files for different settings would work around this problem, but it would be rather awkward. Maybe there is a font file generator that has real support to OpenType features, but I haven’t met one in the wild.

What you can do is to use the .ttf files as hosted on your own server. That is, download the .ttf files for all typefaces that you will use, upload them onto your server, and refer to them in `@font-face` rules. A downside is that then Source Sans Pro won’t be used at all on browsers that lack [support to .ttf](http://caniuse.com/#feat=ttf) for downloadable fonts, most importantly IE 8 and older (and Android 2.1). Perhaps more importantly, the quality of rendering may be worse than when using other font formats like .wof.

Demo, using a single (regular) typeface:

```
<!doctype html>
<style>
body { font-size: 18pt }
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro';
    src: url('sourcesanspro-regular-webfont.ttf') format('truetype');
}
p { 
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
}
.otf {
    -moz-font-feature-settings: "ss01" 1, "onum" 1;
    -webkit-font-feature-settings: "ss01" 1, "onum" 1;
    font-feature-settings: "ss01" 1, "onum" 1;
}
</style>
<p>Hello world! Look at my l’s and numbers: 1234567890.</p>
<p class=otf>Hello world! Look at my l’s and numbers: 1234567890. (OTF enabled)</p>
```